# Value function iteration with stochastic productivity's standard deviation

Tags: macroeconomics, dynamic-programming, dynamic-optimization, stochastic-processes, recursive-macroeconomics

Hello I would like to know how would you discretize the AR(1) process of technology in a standart RBC model when there is stochastic productivity's standard deviation. Namely I have:

Technology $Z_t$ follows a log-normal AR(1) process with stochastic volatility $\sigma_{t}^{Z}$ :
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log Z_{t} &=\rho^{Z} \log Z_{t-1}+\sigma_{t}^{Z} \varepsilon_{t}^{Z} \\
\varepsilon_{t}^{Z} & \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
\end{aligned}
$$
with stochastic volatility $\sigma_{t}^{Z}$ also following a log-normal process
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log \sigma_{t}^{Z} &=\left(1-\rho^{S V}\right) \log \bar{\sigma}+\rho^{S V} \log \sigma_{t-1}^{Z}+\varepsilon_{t}^{S V} \\
\varepsilon_{t}^{S V} & \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^{S V}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

To discretize $Z_t$ I usually use the Tauchen-Hussey procedure, but since  $\sigma_{t}^{Z}$ is now stochastic I don't know how to do it anymore.

Thank you

Comment: See section 4.1 of [Farmer and Toda: Discretizing Stochastic Processes with Exact
Conditional Moments](https://www.mcgill.ca/economics/files/economics/alexis_akira_toda.pdf). I think this uses exactly your specification.